# PHP Array How to Output All Permutations

Tags: php, arrays

given  an array

```
$array= ['apple','banana','coconut']
```

i want to output

> ```
> apple, banana
> apple, coconut
> banana, coconut
> ```

not any reverse combination, nor i need `apple,banana,coconut`

Comment: Those aren't permutations. Anyway, you can do it with nested loops.

Comment: wtf guys, If I knew how to do it I would have done by myself

Comment: with 8k it would be nice if you at least tried

Comment: 8K = 8k questions because im ignorant

Comment: I think his point is that after 6 years on the site and 8K reputation, you should know the proper way to ask questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those aren't permutations; permutations are reorderings of a collection (e.g. `a,b,c`, `b,a,c`, `b,c,a`). What you're asking for are combinations of 2 elements of the collection.

You can do it with nested loops.

```
$len = count($array);
for ($i = 0; $i < $len-1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < $len; $j++) {
        echo $array[$i] . ", " . $array[$j] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Notice that the inner loop starts from the next element after the one in the outer loop. That ensures that you don't get any repeats that are a previous pair in the reverse order -- it's always pairing an element and something to the right of it.